# Text Case in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm trying to get the text in upper case in a list.  The column is a choice column where i typed all the options in upper case.  In searching this site and others it says to create a calculated column and use =UPPER([Column Name]) so i did that.  However, even that column still shows in lower case.  My columns are UnitOfMeasure and Unit.  The formula I'm using is =UPPER(UnitOfMeasure)

The other weird thing is when i first open my list both columns show in upper case, but then after a few seconds they show only the first letter capitalized.

Comment: Please make sure to always include your SharePoint version in your post or tags.  Capabilities and functionality can vary greatly from one version to the next.  If you are using SharePoint 2019 or SharePoint Online, please also specify whether you are using the "classic" or "modern" user interface.

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Online with the modern interface

Comment: I tested as your steps, all could work well. Did you meet this issue when testing on another list? Please try to create a new list and create needed columns, then test again, compare the result.

Comment: It seems to work on some, but not others.  I have this site for Customer Service and another for Engineering.  The Engineering site doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with "Format this column" in modern list views!

[image]

Here, the "Branch" choice column has applied the following JSON:

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "text-transform": "uppercase"
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, there is a `toLowerCase()` function - but no `toUpperCase()`. CSS to the rescue!

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfectly.

Comment: Excellent! Please remember to give a vote and mark answers that solves your questions to help others.

Comment: Is there an option to text transform to Sentence case? either "sentence" or "proper" or something of the sort? "text-transform": "uppercase"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform - i think you are looking for "capitalize"